# java and simplexml framework, how to serialize a method output

Tags: java, serialization, simple-framework

i would like to serlialize a method output like in the class below.

```
@Root
public class Camera {
 public enum Mode {
    CONTINIOUS, TRIGGERED, DEACTIVATED;
 }

@Element
private Mode currMode;
@Element
private int interval;
@Element
private int beforeEvent;
@Element
private int afterEvent;
@Element
private String savePath;

    public Camera(Mode currMode, int interval, int beforeEvent, int afterEvent,
         String savePath) {
     super();
     this.currMode = currMode;
     this.interval = interval;
     this.beforeEvent = beforeEvent;
     this.afterEvent = afterEvent;
     this.savePath = savePath;
 }


@ElementList(entry = "mode", name = "availableModes")
public ArrayList<Mode> getAvailableModes() {
     return new ArrayList<Mode>(Arrays.asList(Mode.values()));
 }
```

}

The method returns all possibilities of an enumeration as List. 
If no default constructor is set, the serialization is completed successfully.

```
<camera>
  <savePath>/images</savePath>
  <currMode>CONTINIOUS</currMode>
   <beforeEvent>5000</beforeEvent>
   <interval>3000</interval>
   <afterEvent>10000</afterEvent>
   <availableModes>
      <mode>CONTINIOUS</mode>
      <mode>TRIGGERED</mode>
      <mode>DEACTIVATED</mode>
   </availableModes>
</camera>
```

However, a default constructor is required for deserialization.
If I set a default constructor, I get the following error during the serialization and deserialization process.

```
Default constructor can not accept read only @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=mode, inline=false, name=availableModes, required=false, type=void) on method 'availableModes' in class Camera
```

During deserialization, the anotated method should be ignored. Is there a possibility to define an element, which will be considered during the serialization process, and which will be ignored during the deserialization process?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure there is some way to set the list, you can add a setter for the list or you can use constructor injection like so.

```
 public Camera(
          @Element(name="currMode") Mode currMode, 
          @Element(name="interval") int interval, 
          @Element(name="beforeEvent") int beforeEvent, 
          @Element(name="afterEvent") int afterEvent,
          @Element(name="savePath") String savePath,
          @ElementList(name="availableModes") List<Mode> availableModes) 
       {
         this.currMode = currMode;
         this.interval = interval;
         this.beforeEvent = beforeEvent;
         this.afterEvent = afterEvent;
         this.savePath = savePath;
       }
```

At any rate the XML serialization process needs to know where it should put the values it found in element "availableMode"